# How to fix rethinkdb connection refused problem?

Tags: python, rethinkdb

I'm following this guide here https://github.com/flaree/Flare-Cogs/tree/master/dankmemer. I got to the import rethinkdb part but I get this error when running the r.connect('localhost', 28015).repl()
command. Been searching yesterday for a fix but couldn't find one.

````
r.connect('localhost', 28015).repl()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 349, in __init__
    self._socket = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rethinkdb/__init__.py", line 93, in connect
    return self.make_connection(self.connection_type, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 830, in make_connection
    return conn.reconnect(timeout=timeout)
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 696, in reconnect
    return self._instance.connect(timeout)
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 538, in connect
    self._socket = SocketWrapper(self, timeout)
  File "/root/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rethinkdb/net.py", line 437, in __init__
    raise ReqlDriverError(
rethinkdb.errors.ReqlDriverError: Could not connect to localhost:28015. Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run rethinkdb first.
Enter your venv, and run `tmux`. Then run `rethinkdb` inside your tmux shell. This starts the rethinkdb server, and keeps it running. Close the SSH session, and open another one. Try running your code again.

Comment: Unhandled rejection ReqlDriverError: First argument to `run` must be an open connection.

Comment: Do you get that when running rethinkDB or when running something else?

Comment: RethinkDb working well. I found in node.js I asynchronous where connection don't meet. As I change code flow, it worked for me. but what you explain not clear, seems did not work.

Comment: The answer I sent is for this specific question, which uses Python. You can see that the person who asked the question accepted my answer, signifying it makes sense & works. Additionally, I can't understand your question. It also seems like you are using javascript, whereas this question is about the database and python, not javascript.